# Convert C# LINQ to VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I'm having some trouble converting this LINQ query in C# to VB.NET.

C#:

```
from row in Users
group row by row.Password_tx into Passes
select new {Password = Passes.Key, Total = Passes.Count()}
```

I've tried to do this in VB.NET but I'm not having much luck. I know the Into syntax is a bit different but I can't figure it out for this occassion.

VB.NET:

```
from row in Users _
group by pass = row.Password_tx into passes = Group _
select with {.passes.Key, .passes.Count()}
```

Comment: Try this converter http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ let me know if it helped :)

Comment: I tried that before making this question and didn't have any luck with it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
From row In Users
Group By pass = row.Password_tx Into passes = Group
Select Password = pass, Total = passes.Count
```

And here is a sample code I used to confirm it's working:

```
Public Class Form1
  Class User
    Friend Property Password_tx As String
    Sub New(pwd As String)
      Password_tx = pwd
    End Sub
  End Class
  Class Users : Inherits Generic.List(Of User)
  End Class

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim u As New Users
    u.Add(New User("abc"))
    u.Add(New User("bcd"))
    u.Add(New User("abc"))

    Dim v = From row In u
            Group By pass = row.Password_tx Into passes = Group
            Select Password = pass, Total = passes.Count
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this one.

```
from row in Users _
group by pass = row.Password_tx into passes = Group _
select New With {.Password = Passes.Key, _ 
                 .Total = Passes.Count()}
```